# How to change the curve on an SVG element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have this function to create a curve between two points

```
var amountOfCurve = (d.noOfSameConnections+1); //between 0 and 10
        var dy = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dx = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) *(amountOfCurve);

        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + (d.target.x) + "," + (d.target.y);
```

Some links have both the same source and target. I solve this in the noOfSameConnections. But what I want is instead of different sized curve, as there can only be a maximum of two links between two nodes, I want the link to curve the other way. So I would do something like this :

```
if(d.noOfSameConnections === 1){
//curve one way
} else {
//curve the other
}
```

But I can't seem to work out how to switch the curve around :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of the arc can be controlled with the `sweep` [flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 500)
        .attr('height', 500);
        
      var d = {
        source: {
          x: 10,
          y: 10
        },
        target: {
          x: 490,
          y: 490
        }
      };
      
     var dy = d.target.x - d.source.x,
         dx = d.target.y - d.source.y,
         dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * 0.8;
         
      var largeSweep = 0;
      var sweep = 1;
        
      svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 " + largeSweep + "," + sweep + " " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("stoke-width", 2);
        
      largeSweep = 0;
      sweep = 0;
        
      svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 " + largeSweep + "," + sweep + " " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "orange")
        .style("stoke-width", 2);
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: nice, I tried that but as you can see I had the variable, amountOfCurve, which obviously changed the amount of curve depending which way it was 'sweeping' that was my problem :) Thank you